# inserting # in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert a # in a stored procedure in SQL Server. When I write it I have a mistake and when I delete it, it works, why?.

The line where I want to write a '#' is this:

```
INSERT INTO @Resultado VALUES ('CB'+'0596'+CAST(@aniomes AS CHAR(6))+SPACE(518)+'#')
```

And I want to write it on the final of the line.

Could you help me?

Comment: I removed that huge glob of code - if there's only one line that's problematic, reduce the code as much as possible. And _always include the error message you're getting_. The best would be a **short** example that we can reproduce, i.e. a 3-line stored proc that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What error do you get.  Also, where is the "#" in that line?  I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Try inserting `char(35)` instead...

Comment: Mens 8152, Level 16, Status 4, PRocedure PA_UYInformeTransacciones, Line 572
Data from String or binary would truncate, this is the mistake

Comment: Is the column in Resultado greater than 531 chars? Its the only thing that could go bad

Answer (score 1):

Use the `insert . . . select` method instead:

```
INSERT INTO @Resultado
    select 'CB'+'0596'+CAST(@aniomes AS CHAR(6))+SPACE(518)
```

It is also a good idea to always list the columns on the table for an `insert`, even if there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

use char(35) for #

```
INSERT INTO @Resultado VALUES ('CB'+'0596'+CAST(@aniomes AS CHAR(6))+SPACE(518)+char(35))
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be incapable of reproducing the error... this worked fine:

```
DECLARE @Resultado TABLE( 
test varchar(5000)
)
INSERT INTO @Resultado VALUES ('CB'+'0596'+CAST('123456' AS CHAR(6))+SPACE(518)+'#')
select * from @Resultado
```

Could it be that you failed to spot the # before the 518 spaces? Or perhaps the column was non nullable and the variable @aniomes was a NULL?